# How can I ignore whitespace changes in TortoiseGit blame

Tags: git, tortoisegit, blame

If I want to ignore whitespace changes in git blame I can use `-w` option. But how can I do it in TortoiseGit Blame GUI tool? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

This answer is apparently no longer valid. See above.

(I can't delete this answer since it is accepted)

OLD ANSWER:

No, it is not possible to ignore whitespace changes in TortoiseGitBlame.

In [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) blame view, whitespace is ignored ([feature added in version 1.51](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/blob/master/GitUI/Resources/ChangeLog.md)).

Comment: I think it is possible to at least choose only those that are really changed and not by whitespaces, right? I did it before. Just forgot how to do it...

Answer (score 4):

See the following figure for `-w`(Ignore whitespace) feature:

[image]

Comment: ... suspect this feature was added some time between the OP (2013) and this answer (2017) .. but got this page as the first google result for my search and this answer is now the correct answer!  Thanks Yue Lin Ho!